Translating the FAQ into Chinese
Although this community is primarily composed of people who can speak both English and Chinese, I'd like to make it a bit user friendly to primarily Chinese speaking vistors, so they are not intimidated, driven away from not being able to speak English well, or even feel obligated to speak English.
I would like to propose that we translate the FAQ page on the main site into Chinese, so that new Chinese speaking users will have a better understanding of how things work.
I would like to ask for the help of the community and it's members in this task. I propose either using Google Documents for sharing, collaborating in this project. I've created a spreadsheet for collaboration here. Everyone should be able to freelt view and edit this spreadsheet (no need to log in). 
I've preserved most of the Markdown for reference purposes.
Feel free to make any changes, edits, or comment that you feel are needed.
Please let me now if there are any issues.
@Cuter44 made a much better formated version and bought up a good point, if we want users in China to be able to collaborate (Google Docs in not allowed in China), we should find other ways to to post and collaborate the questions and their answers. 
I will be posting each question and translation pair as a separate answer for users to do a review. 
My goal right now is to get as much translated as possible and later QC the translation with everyone's help.
The translation is more or less complete. Thanks to everyone involved. Please leave your user names in the comments (or edit this question), so you may receive the recognition you deserve. :)
Thanks to Cuter44 and other collaborators.
I realize the translation may be off in terms or word choice and grammar, so I am seeking the guidance of the more knowledgeable and experienced sets of this community for better insight. 
Please make any revision as you see fit and leave any questions of comments pertaining to the rough translations.
Status: 7/19 questions posted.

What can I ask here?
Can I request a translation?
Should I post in English or Chinese?
Can I ask for resources?
What shouldn't I ask here?
How do I ask?
Etiquette


Q2: 我可以要求翻译吗？
A2: 我们不禁止的翻译要求，但需要注意，这不是一个翻译服务网站，所以我们将关闭任何不表明努力研究的翻译要求。问问题时请你仔细和清楚地解释你的意图。

Q5: 什么样的问题不应该问？
A5: 您应该只要求实际和交代健谈的问题。开放式的和健谈的问题削弱我们的网站的实用性，并从本网推下其他可有益的问题。
您的问题应该是合理的范围内。如果你能想象一整本书来回答您的问题，那您问的太多了。
如果你的动机的提问：“我想参加一个讨论______”，那么你不应该在这里问这个问题。但是，如果你的动机是：“我希望别人给我解释______”，那么你问的应该没问题。 这不是说讨论在本网不受欢迎的。我们欢迎您在我们的实时网络聊天屋里讨论任何和中文有关的题目。）
为了防止你的问题被标志而删除，我们要求您避免问有这列主观题的问题...

每个问题的答案都同样有效：“什么是你最喜欢的______？”
你的回答在你的的问题里，并且您希望更多的答案：“我用________ 来做______，你有什么？”
有没有实际需要解决的问题：“我很好奇，如果其他人都觉得像我这样做。”
我们正被提出一个不限成员的名额，假设性的问题：“如果______发生了... 怎么办？”
是一个夸夸其谈伪装成一个问题：“______太烂了，你说对吧？”

（以上部分是改编自MetaFilter的常见问题解答。 如果您想了解更多详细信息，请参阅6伟大的主观题的指引。）
如果你的问题是关于网站本身，请不问在这里问。 访问我们的荟萃讨论网站，在那里你可以谈论关于网站的事情，比如什么样的问题是适当的，应该使用什么样的标签，建议一个功能，指出了一个错误，或讨论本站的一般如何的运作。

Q1: 我能问什么问题?
A1: Stack Exchange 汉语分站是一个为专家, 语言爱好者以及对汉语感兴趣的人所设立的. 无论汉语是不是你的母语, 这都是一个为你而设的地方. 这个网站讨论汉语的的细微之处, 以及一些不那么专业但是在学习汉语时可能遇到的相关问题, 又或者仅仅是因为你想知道为什么是这样。
如果您想看话题内和话题外的详单, 请点这里。

Q3: 用英文还是用中文来发表更合适？ 
A3: 可以用中文或英文两语言问答。荟萃讨论网站允许英文问答。这是一个Stack Exchange团队的请求。使他们能够与我们顺利沟通。
因此，在这主站点中，您可以用中文或英文问答，但我们建议的在别的Stack Exchange也用的方针：

如果这个问题是英文的，请以英文作答
如果问题是中文的，请以中文作答

在这两种情况下，如果你不适合用和原帖作者提问的语言，你可以在提问的语言提供一个简短但完整的答案，然后用你更适合的语言来写一个更详细的回答。其他用户可能会帮你提供好的翻译。翻译不是要勉强的，只是对双语不完全流利的用户有帮助。但请注意，不提供翻译的情况下，如果你的答案是正确的，原帖作者可能不懂所以不会考虑。

Are these FAQ machine translated? The usage of words seems a bit odd. But I can't edit it.

Q4: 我可以要求(语言学习)材料吗？
A4: 简短的回答是：不可以，但视情况而定。
这是一个在初期测试时用在材料标签常见的问题。这些问题目前都被锁定，因为他们是不适合的问答格式。在任何情况下，因为它们是高度要求，我们成立组语言学习材料的问题。你可以自由添加更多的材料，但请看一下说明，再发布。
如果您要求一个材料列表，请注意您的问题的目的。开放式的和健谈的问题。Stack Exchange网里不鼓励开放式的和健谈的问题。 “真的问题有答案”这帖子给你这个忠告：
你应该只要求问对你有实际和交代健谈的问题。开放式的和健谈的问题削弱我们的网站的实用性，并从本网推下其他可有益的问题。
我们不是说您不应该问一个建议列表的问题。问问题时请把具体的内容说清。例如 棋盘游戏来练习口语。避免含糊不清的问题，如 “哪里有一些好点儿学习中文的网站呢？” 因为它们会被关闭。
如果你有一个健谈开放式的问题，请访问我们的聊天室。
问问题前请你看看您的问题已经被问过了吗。
如果您觉得你有个对别人有帮助问题和答案，您可以回答自己的问题。

Q6: 这里我怎么问问题？
A6: 当你发布一个新的问题，其他用户将立即能看到，并尝试提供好答案。这种情况经常发生在短短的几分钟内，所以一定要经常检查你的问题，最好的回应仍然是在你刚问得那时。
对您的问题的评论会在本站收件箱（在每页左上方）出现一个红色指示灯在全球，点击查看。
未读收件箱中的邮件 http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-global-inbox-unread.png
如果您的问题需要澄清，你会在您的问题的下边看到键入意见。
评论 http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-comments.png
如果其他用户要求的更多信息，在评论中你可以编辑您的问题。请你使用的编辑链接，仅低于你原来的问题。
编辑 http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-edit.png
及时提供澄清将帮助你能受到最好的答案。
正如你看到了新的答案，如果是对您有帮助的话，请您通过答案左侧的上下箭头点击向上箭头，投赞成票。
投票 http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-answer-voting.png
答案通常是通过投票得分排序，所以投赞成票的答案浮到顶部。其他用户也会与您一样投答案的票。
当你决定哪个答案是对你最有帮助的，请您标记它为接受的答案，点击答案左侧的复选框轮廓。
接受的答案 http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png
这让其他用户知道你的问题收到了一个对你满意的回答。这样做显示你承认其他用户的努力，得到社会的价值。 （如果你不这样做，其他用户们可能往往会礼貌地邀请您回来并接受您问题的答案！）

Q7: 礼仪
A7: 礼貌是在任何时候都需要的； 无礼的行为是不会被容忍的。
对人友好
对待别人象你希望他们把你同样的尊重。我们都在这里一起学习。有些人可能不于您那样有知识。请您把您的幽默感拿出来。
要诚实
最重要的是要诚实。如果你看到有差错的帖子，请您投反对票。 也请您评论表示，具体是在那里有错。您也可以自己提供更好的答案。最好的话请您修改和改进存在的问题和答案！
